# Groups of units: Find an explicit isomorphism $U_{35}$, $U_{39}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I need help in the following exercise:

Find an explicit isomorphism between $U(\mathbb{Z}/35\mathbb{Z})$ and $U(\mathbb{Z}/39\mathbb{Z})$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the structure of those groups?

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Note that $\mathbb Z_{35}\cong\mathbb Z_7\times\mathbb Z_5$ and so we have $$U_{35}=(\mathbb Z_{35})^{\times}\cong(\mathbb Z_7)^{\times}\times(\mathbb Z_5)^{\times}\cong\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_6\cong\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_{12}$$ The same can be done for another group. So,$$U_{39}=(\mathbb Z_{39})^{\times}\cong(\mathbb Z_{13})^{\times}\times(\mathbb Z_3)^{\times}\cong\mathbb Z_{12}\times\mathbb Z_2$$ Now think of a proper map which takes a generator from $U_{35}$ onto a generator of $U_{39}$.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "a generator", as the groups aren't cyclic.

Comment: yes, I was tinking about that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I mean a generating set. For example $\{2,6\}$ map to $\{2,38\}$.

Comment: That are the generating sets??